# how to call controller function from run block with id in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call controller function from run block.

HTML

```
<div id="yourcontroller" ng-app="" data-ng-controller="mainController" data-module="yourcontroller">
</div>
```

And inside my run I'm trying to call the controller function like below

```
angular.module('modulename', [])

    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window ) {

    $scope.yourControllerMethod = function(){
             console.log("inside yourControllerMethod");
        };

    }])

   .run(function($rootScope, $log, $window) {
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('yourcontroller')).scope();
            scope.yourControllerMethod();
        });
```

But, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yourControllerMethod' of undefined`

Can someone answer where I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the module in the ng-app attribute and the controller is myCtrl not yourcontroller.

```
<div id="myCtrl" ng-app="modulename" data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-module="yourcontroller">
</div>
```

I am also not sure if the app has bootstraped by the time the run is called.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need the scope in order to call the method? I did something similar from plain JavaScript code. But things to mention: I linked ng-app to the body, attached a handler on a ready event, didn't use scope, but controller() function directly. Hope this helps:

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('myInputId');
    input.onkeypress = function (event) {
      if (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          angular.element(document.body).controller().aMethodFromTheController();
        }
      }
    }
  });
```